# S3 Select retrieve headers in the CSV

Tags: python, csv, amazon-s3, export-to-csv, boto3

I am trying to fetch a subset of records from a CSV stored in an S# bucket using the following code:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
bucket = bucket
file_name = file

sql_stmt = """SELECT S.* FROM s3object S LIMIT 10"""


req = s3.select_object_content(
    Bucket=bucket,
    Key=file,
    ExpressionType='SQL',
    Expression=sql_stmt,
    InputSerialization = {'CSV': {'FileHeaderInfo': 'USE'}},
    OutputSerialization = {'CSV': {}},
)

records = []
for event in req['Payload']:
    if 'Records' in event:
        records.append(event['Records']['Payload'])
    elif 'Stats' in event:
        stats = event['Stats']['Details']


file_str = ''.join(r.decode('utf-8') for r in records)

select_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(file_str))
df = pd.DataFrame(select_df)
print(df)
```

This successfully yields the records but misses out on headers.

I read here [S3 Select CSV Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50848573/s3-select-csv-headers) that S3 Select does not yield headers at all. So, is it possible to retrieve the headers of a CSV file in S3 in any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `InputSerialization={'CSV': {"FileHeaderInfo": "Use"}},`

TO `InputSerialization={'CSV': {"FileHeaderInfo": "NONE"}},`

Then, it will print full content, including the `header`.

Explanation:

`FileHeaderInfo` accepts one of "NONE" OR "USE" OR "IGNORE".

Use `NONE` option rather then `USE`, it will then print `header` as well, as `NONE` tells that you need `header` as well for `processing`.

Here is reference. https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.select_object_content

I hope it helps.

Comment: If I am reading parquet file instead of csv, then is there any way to get the headers in the result? I get only rows currently of the parquet file.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me when I am adding `where` clause in the sql query

Answer (score 2):

Red Boy's solution doesn't allow you to use the column names in the query and instead, you have to use the column indexes. 
This wasn't good for me so my solution was to do another query to only get the headers and concatenate them with the actual query result. This is on JavaScript but the same should apply to Python:

```
      const params = {
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: "file.csv",
        ExpressionType: 'SQL',
        Expression: `select * from s3object s where s."date" >= '${fromDate}'`,
        InputSerialization: {'CSV': {"FileHeaderInfo": "USE"}},
        OutputSerialization: {'CSV': {}},
      };

      //s3 select doesn't return the headers, so need to run another query to only get the headers (see '{"FileHeaderInfo": "NONE"}')
      const headerParams = {
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: "file.csv",
        ExpressionType: 'SQL',
        Expression: "select * from s3object s limit 1", //this will only get the first record of the csv, and since we are not parsing headers, they will be included
        InputSerialization: {'CSV': {"FileHeaderInfo": "NONE"}},
        OutputSerialization: {'CSV': {}},
      };

      //concatenate header + data -- getObject is a method that handles the request
      return await this.getObject(s3, headerParams) + await this.getObject(s3, params);
```

Answer (score 1):

To short,

> FileHeaderInfo (string) -- Describes the first line of input.
>
> Valid values are:
>
> **NONE** : First line is not a header.
>
> **IGNORE** : First line is a header,
> but you can't use the header values to indicate the column in an expression. You can use column position (such as _1, _2, …) to indicate the column (SELECT s._1 FROM OBJECT s ).
>
> **Use** : First line is
> a header, and you can use the header value to identify a column in an expression (SELECT "name" FROM OBJECT ).