# AWS S3 SELECT WebUI error: "Quoted record delimiter found in the file"

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-s3-select

I am trying to the Select From for CSV in AWS S3 SELECT Web UI, but I get the following error msg:

```
Quoted record delimiter found in the file. To allow quoted record delimiters, please set AllowQuotedRecordDelimiter to 'TRUE'.
```

But there is no option to set `AllowQuotedRecordDelimiter` to `TRUE`

Please advise

[image]

Comment: I think you need python boto module for this to work. Add the parameter to s3.select_object_content. For e.g.  InputSerialization = {'CSV': {"FileHeaderInfo": "Use", 'AllowQuotedRecordDelimiter': True,}}, as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50848573/s3-select-csv-headers

Comment: It's a pity that this is not available in the UI. Shouldn't have to run a script just to do an S3 Select

Comment: 1 year later - AllowQuotedRecordDelimiter  SHOULD default to TRUE in the UI but still doesn't.

Comment: and another year passed :)

Comment: yes, this should have been an easy fix for AWS team and quick win for the UI.

Comment: This is still an issue. I just submitted a feature request for S3 SELECT to expose all input and output settings using the "Feedback" button in the bottom left-hand corner of the AWS Console. I recommend everyone do the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a " in the custom field under the CSV delimiter section,
see picture bellow (This did the trick for me):

[image: Changes require photo here]

Answer (score 0):

While writing to_csv

set sep = ' " '

```
pd.to_csv('example_df.csv',sep='"')
```

It should work.