# S3 Select (python) does not return the header when using WHERE clause despite FileHeaderInfo=NONE

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-s3-select

When I submit this query:
`SELECT * FROM s3object` with the `FileHeaderInfo` of the input serialization set to `NONE`, I get the records expected with their header.

As soon as I add a where clause like this:

```
SELECT * FROM s3object  WHERE _3 = 'Chicago'
```

then the header is no longer returned.

Comment: Might be helpful: [amazon web services - S3 Select CSV Headers - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50848573/s3-select-csv-headers)

Comment: Thank you John. I've taken all those suggestions into consideration. I'm using NONE